# Forecasting a time series multiple steps ahead

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I've been reading up on time series forecasting, but most of what I've come across assumes that we want to predict the next value in a series.  As such, I have access to lagged values (maybe I look at `t-4, t-3, ..., t` when I predict the value at `t+1`).

Suppose I want to predict the next two weeks worth of values.  Now I run into trouble, because I can make my first prediction using lagged values, but my second prediction (`t+2`) will be missing the true value for `t+1`.  I'll have my prediction for `t+1`, but that seems far inferior to the using the ground truth.

Are there standard ways this is handled in?

Comment: software takes the prediction for the next period and uses it as an estimate of the actual to predict the subsequent period and so on .....

Comment: @IrishStat This is only correct when the model is linear. In general the conditional expectation must be computed.

Answer (score 1):

'Recursive forecasting' uses your t+1 forecast value in its estimate of t+2.  'Direct forecasting' solves for a unique equation/set of coefficients for each future time period: t+1, t+2 etc.  Rob Hyndman discusses this more in depth in the following link, and I personally have found direct forecasting to perform better long-term as it results in less propagation of errors.

[Recursive and Direct Forecasting](https://robjhyndman.com/publications/rectify/)